# ajax based jquery data table sending columns as "columns"=>"[object Object]"

Tags: jquery, datatables

jQuery ajax data table is sending the parameters for filters as following array
How to change it send actual value and name of column?

```
Parameters: {
"draw"=>"2", 
"columns"=>"[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]", "order"=>"[object Object]", 
"start"=>"0", 
"length"=>"10", 
"search"=>"[object Object]"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Add fnServerData in your Datatable config.

```
 "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings) {

                $.ajax({
                    "dataType": 'json',
                    "type": "GET",
                    "url": "/Home/AjaxGetJsonData",
                    "data": oSettings.oAjaxData,
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "success": function (json) {
                       fnCallback(json);
                    }
                });

            }
```

Comment: I have now added

if(oSettings.sAjaxSource === null){
       aoData = oSettings.oAjaxData;
 }

...before the Ajax call and it works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

The same issue for me. I figured out that the reason was my past setting of jquery **jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true**. Remove this setting works for me

Answer (score 0):

If you are using fnServerData, that might be your problem. You can migrate to using the preXhr.dt instead.

```
var oTable = $('#my-table')
    .on('preXhr.dt', function ( e, settings, data ) {
        ...
    }).DataTable({
        "serverSide": "true",
        "ajax": '/indexData',
        ...
    });
```

Here's why:

Using fnServerData triggers a section in the _fnBuildAjax function, which converts the data **object** into an **array**. This in turn triggers logic in jQuery.ajax, which expects that "If an array was passed in, assume that it is an array of form elements."

So it uses a very simple **non-recursive** method of converting the parameters into a parameter string. And since it's non-recursive, second level objects get translated as simply as [object+Object], instead of with their nested properties etc.